# How to convert Date and time format in r?

Tags: r, lubridate

I am having a dataset that looks like this :

```
Mno    Date and time      value
123 23-01-2021 08:03:04     23
234 23-01-2021 08:03:04     25
345 23-01-2021 08:03:04     26
456 23-01-2021 08:03:04     27
```

I want only time to be in 00:00:00

```
Mno Date and time       value
123 23-01-2021 00:00:00  23
234 23-01-2021 00:00:00  25
345 23-01-2021 00:00:00  26
456 23-01-2021 00:00:00  27
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub` to do this via regex -

```
df$Date <- sub('\\d+:\\d+:\\d+', '00:00:00', df$Date)
df

#  Mno                Date value
#1 123 23-01-2021 00:00:00    23
#2 234 23-01-2021 00:00:00    25
#3 345 23-01-2021 00:00:00    26
#4 456 23-01-2021 00:00:00    27
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `lubridate`:

```r
yourdataframe$`Date and Time` <- update(yourdataframe$`Date and Time`,hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
```

it might seem that it only rembers the date, but this is formatting quirk of the PosiXct.

it will calculate the timeline correct. To demonstrate, this will be the Datetime Vector if we add an hour to the datetime:

```
yourdataframe$`Date and Time` <- yourdataframe$`Date and Time`+ hours(1)
yourdataframe$`Date and Time`
#[1] "2021-01-23 01:00:00 UTC"
#[2] "2021-01-23 01:00:00 UTC"
#[3] "2021-01-23 01:00:00 UTC"
#[4] "2021-01-23 01:00:00 UTC"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)


df$Date <- dmy_hms(df$Date) %>%
  as_date() %>%
  format.Date("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S") 

  Mno                Date value
1 123 23-01-2021 00:00:00    23
2 234 23-01-2021 00:00:00    25
3 345 23-01-2021 00:00:00    26
4 456 23-01-2021 00:00:00    27
```

`as_date` keep only the date, that you reformat with the 00 for the time with `format.Date`

---

data:

```
df <- read.csv(text = "
Mno    ;Date      ;value
123   ;23-01-2021 08:03:04;     23
234   ;23-01-2021 08:03:04;     25
345   ;23-01-2021 08:03:04;     26
456   ;23-01-2021 08:03:04;     27",sep = ";")
```